# Do harbours have a code equivalent to ICAO

Tags: database

Each airport has a code that identifies it. I am looking for a similar primary key for a harbour. Is there such a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here's the comprehensive list with info on codes etc
http://exportvirginia.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Seaports-of-the-World.pdf

Comment: You might want to add the original source. http://www.unece.org/cefact/locode/service/location